# Parse X-Forwarded-For to get ip with werkzeug on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, ip, flask, werkzeug

Heroku proxies requests from a client to server, so you have to parse the X-Forwarded-For to find the originating IP address.

The general format of the X-Forwarded-For is:

```
X-Forwarded-For: client1, proxy1, proxy2
```

Using werkzeug on flask, I'm trying to come up with a solution in order to access the originating IP of the client.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Werkzeug (and Flask) store headers in an instance of [`werkzeug.datastructures.Headers`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Headers).  You should be able to do something like this:

```
provided_ips = request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")
# The first entry in the list should be the client's IP.
```

Alternately, you could use [`request.access_route`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.access_route) (thanks @Bastian for pointing that out!):

```
provided_ips = request.access_route
# First entry in the list is the client's IP
```

Comment: you might want to check http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.access_route

Comment: @Bastian the link you posted says "if forwarded header exists" which I understand would be `X-Forwarded-For` , so in case forwarded header does not exists would the access_route function will work , I do not have any place to test my flask app other than heroku.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use in Django. See this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host

Note: At least on Heroku HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR will be an array of IP addresses. The first one is the client IP the rest are proxy server IPs.

in settings.py:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```

in your views.py:

```
if 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' in request.META:
    ip_adds = request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].split(",")   
    ip = ip_adds[0]
else:
    ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Comment: Please read [this note about the last IP in `X-Forwarded-For` being the only reliable one on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18517550/429091) (unless you trust clients from outside of Heroku to not lie about themselves…